# Qualifiers for a variable in C++

Tags: c++

How do I know if qualifiers like `const` etc are associated with the passed arguments to a function?

e.g.

```
template<class T>
void callback(T & data)
{
  body of function
}
```

How do I know if the data is `const` etc?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  We are not entirely sure how this function is supposed to be called.

Comment: @Beta You can still have a const argument by explicitly specifying `T` explicitly as `const SomeType`.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin: You're right, my comment was careless and incorrect. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether a type (including a template type argument) is const qualified using a standard type trait:

```
bool is_const = std::is_const_v<T>;
```

If `T` is const qualified, then and only then is `T&` a reference to const.

Whether or not the referred object is const is something that cannot be inspected.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.